# How to center a group of widgets in Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I'm new to **Android Studio** and mobile app developing and I'm trying to create the **layout of an activity**. My desire is to include in order: (1) a picture (2) a big text (2) a smaller text, grouped vertically and centered on the screen. I tried using `android:layout_gravity="center"` but it centers the group of widgets only horizontally. How to make it center in both ways? Here's the relative code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/my_image_id"
            android:src="@drawable/my_image"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/first_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="40sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/second_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put all code in relative layout and set  layout_width and height wrap_content of Main Linear Layout and set centerinparent=true in main linear layout.

Comment: add `android:gravity="center"` for your top most `LinearLayout`

Comment: You can also get rid of one unused linear layout here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added **android:gravity="center"** to parent LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_image_id"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/first_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/second_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Moreover (1) the second vertical linear layout is useless now (as @Pycpik said) and (2) all the `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` in the 3 widgets are useless as well.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout's layout_gravity is unidirectional.You are right.

Answer (score 0):

@ Robb1 you can do this by this code ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.stackoverflow_test.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="first_text"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="second_text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```